# Can we share an image on WhatsApp with react share

Tags: reactjs, react-share

I am using react-share to share the URL and title on WhatsApp using WhatsappShareButton. And I want to share an image along with the URL. Is there any alternative way for this

**Code:**

```
<WhatsappShareButton
  url="https://www.google.com/maps"
  title="hello this is text"
  imageUrl="https://imgurl"
  imgAlt="image"
>
  <WhatsappIcon size={30} round={true} />
</WhatsappShareButton>;
```

Comment: "I want add an image in that shared url. Is it possible to share image by this." I have absolutely no idea what this means.  What is a "shared url"?  What does "share image" mean in this context?

Comment: I think you can share the image link only

Comment: If you can't give clear and exact definitions of what you mean and what you want this question is unanswerable.

Comment: I want to share image not the image Link while we click on the Whatsapp Icon

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. You can only share the image URL that is there and not an image itself.

Comment: Is there another way to share the image along with the text

Comment: You can share the image url along. That is the best way I feel.